# VBA syntax for copying ranges

Tags: vba

All I need is to use variables to copy the data in one sheet (ws1) to the other (ws2) - as values only.

I though this would work but it does not:

```
ws2.Range(Cells(StrtRow, 2), Cells(lRow, lCol)) = _
ws1.Range(Cells(StrtRow, 2), Cells(lRow, lCol))
```

However this works:

```
ws2.Range.Cells(1, 1) = ws1.Range.Cells(53, 2)
```

The issue is I need to select a range using variables, not just a cell...surprisingly enough this does not work either:

```
ws2.Range(Cells(53, 2), Cells(471, 46)) =  _
ws1.Range(Cells(53, 2), Cells(471, 46))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ranges inside of `Range()` must refer to the `Cells` on the same `Worksheet`

`ws1.Range(Cells(StrtRow, 2), Cells(lRow, lCol))` will only work properly if `ws1` is the `ActiveSheet` because an unqualified range automatically refers to a range on the `ActiveSheet`

Here is the proper syntax:

```
ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(StrtRow, 2), ws2.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Value = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(StrtRow, 2), ws1.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Value
```

Comment: Thomas - thanks! This worked and it will help me a lot with the rest of my coding...I did not know that is the way vba would go about it. Really appreciate the help. Cheers!